# Racket: How would I return list of symbols from a tree?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define-struct sample [color upper lower])

(define v (make-sample 'brown empty empty))
(define w (make-sample 'blue empty empty))
(define x (make-sample 'green v w))
(define y (make-sample 'orange empty empty))
(define z (make-sample 'blue x y))
```

I'm trying to make a function color-list that takes a sample and gives back a list of symbols of all the colors in its tree.
for example

```
;(color-lst z) should return (list 'blue 'green 'brown 'blue 'orange))
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please post the relevant code, pointing specific problems with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to traverse the tree using a [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order), taking care of correctly creating an output list as you go. Following the standard template for a tree traversal is easy, you just need to know *where* to call the recursion and where to put the current element. I'll give you some hints, and won't spoil the fun of reaching your own answer. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (color-lst tree)
  (if (empty? tree) ; if the tree is empty
      <???>         ; it's the base case for building an output list
      (append (cons <???>              ; else add current element
                    (color-lst <???>)) ; recurse on one side
              (color-lst <???>))))     ; and then on the other
```

If everything's fine, it should work as expected:

```
(color-lst z)
=> '(blue green brown blue orange)
```

Comment: This operates on lists, not samples, because you call `null?` directly on the argument.

Comment: No, the recursion ends when we reach one of the leaves in the struct, which happens to be an empty list. But alright, I'll change to `empty?` to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly simply using a recursive function.

```
; sample? -> (listof symbol?)
(define (color-lst sample)
  (cond
    [(sample? sample)
     (cons (sample-color sample)
           (append (color-lst (sample-upper sample))
                   (color-lst (sample-lower sample))))]
    [(empty? sample) sample]
    [else (raise-argument-error 'color-lst "(or/c symbol? null?)" sample)]))

(color-lst z)
; => '(blue green brown blue orange)
```

This works by walking the tree of symbols and building a list as it goes. If it doesn't find a symbol or an empty list for one of the tree's nodes, it will fail with a nicely-formatted error message.

Comment: It's simpler than that. And maaaybe we shouldn't give a straight solution, given that OP didn't show any effort on his part (and this is probably a homework)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez OP wants `color-lst` to accept a `sample`, not a list. Also, I sort of disagree with the philosophy of giving partial answers on SO, even if it *could* be a homework question.

Comment: I'm following the naming convention on the question. My answer works for samples, not lists.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) IMHO it's ok to give complete answers to people who have _at least tried_. If that's not the case, SO should not be a homework service, it's not fair with whoever posed the question to the OP.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I don't necessarily disagree, but then I'd rather close the question than give a partial answer. Though I suppose there's a difference between homework questions on extremely common tags like [tag:java] vs something like [tag:racket].